# Is an HTML aria-label attribute allowed to be an empty string?

Tags: html, reactjs, specifications, wai-aria, screen-readers

Will an empty string be ignored by screen readers or should i avoid adding them to the element if the string is empty?

For reference, this is a usecase in react where you want to default to an empty string to avoid having to check for undefined:

```
<input
  id={id}
  value={value}
  {...(ariaLabel ? { 'aria-label': ariaLabel } : {})}
/>
```

Answer (score 4):

I can't see anything in the spec about what should happen if `aria-label` is set to an empty string. I think that you'd just be labelling it with nothing and thus it'd be fine, but I can imagine a screen reader assuming that's a mistake and falling back to something else.

I think you're using `aria-label` wrong if it can be empty some times. `aria-label` is just a stand-in for the `<label>` element. It's supposed to name the input element. There shouldn't be a situation where the name changes or can be blank.

Comment: if you're creating a reusable input component, then the label is set dynamically from the input components properties. If the button has a label  of its own, then we don't need to add an aria-label attribute.

Comment: aria-label can be used with of lot of HTML markup. Using aria-label on an input element is just one case.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation from w3 makes no mention of an empty attribute value for `aria-label`. So it's probably implementation defined of the different screenreader software.

Reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-label

Answer (score 1):

Empty `aria-label` should absolutely be avoided as it can cause screen readers to do unpredictable things. While it is not something that is explicitly forbidden by WCAG, it could be be considered a violation of WCAG Guideline 4.1:

"Maximize compatibility with current and future user agents, including assistive technologies."

Empty `aria-label` serves no purpose, introduces cruft in the code, and is a sign of lazy programming.

Comment: Please add details and references for your statements e.g. "it can cause screen readers to do unpredictable things". Also while I don't see how this would violate 4.1 (it's a guideline, not a SC, and it doesn't look like this would violate any of the 4.1.x SCs), I agree that avoiding if you don't need it would be better (cf. the first rule of ARIA)